# I have made a custom check box by having an outside div having a tick inside it .. now the active class is not getting applied

Tags: html, css, sass

This is my html code

```
  <div class="row-div" v-for="user in UserList">
     <div style="width: 25%" class="name-checkbox">
        <div class="square">
        <input id="chk1" name="chk" type="checkbox">
        <label for="chk1"> 
        </label>
     </div>
     <div>
        {{user.firstName}} {{user.lastName}}
     </div>
  </div>
```

I am now using v-for but if i click on any other square other than the first one the first one gets activated not the respective checkbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using CSS, check updated snippet below.

```css
.square input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}
.square {
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.square input[type=checkbox] + label{
  padding-left: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}




.square input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
  background: black url(http://www.clker.com/cliparts/R/C/5/I/G/P/green-light-tick-mark-md.png) no-repeat center center;
  background-size: 16px auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="square"><input id="chk" name="chk" type="checkbox"><label for="chk"></label></div>
<div class="square"><input id="chk1" name="chk" type="checkbox"><label for="chk1"></label></div>
<div class="square"><input id="chk2" name="chk" type="checkbox"><label for="chk2"></label></div>
<div class="square"><input id="chk3" name="chk" type="checkbox"><label for="chk3"></label></div>
<div class="square"><input id="chk4" name="chk" type="checkbox"><label for="chk4"></label></div>
```

Comment: i have updated the answer, you just replace path in CSS

Comment: ya its done one more issue i am facing how can i set the size of the click i mean if i want to decrease the size of the tick(background-image)how can i do it

Comment: you can update in css i have already given all the sizes in css

Comment: hey there actually i have 10 checkboxes but if i click on 2nd checkbox then also the tick appears only on the first one how can i resolve this

Comment: and i am making it in vuejs so please give me a solution for this problem which will run in vuejs without any issues

Comment: Every checkbox should have unique `id` and linked `label` should have same `id` in `for attribute`. check updated answer

Comment: hi if i now use v-for for the same 10 checkboxes how will i render the ticks on each individual record i have updated the code

Comment: please give me a  solution for the same

Comment: @user9563422 check snippet in answer

Comment: i am not able to see it

Comment: what should i mention here in front of chk ?? <input id="chk1" name="chk" type="checkbox">
        <label for="chk1">